# Effects of empty state of FIFO

Tags: verilog

I have a basic question about FIFO.

There are EMPTY and FULL flag behaviors corresponding to empty and full state of FiFo. About full state of FiFo, I can understand why it is bad for design because Fifo will not accept any coming data after full flag is asserted.

**But about the EMPTY state, does it have any bad effects** ? Because I see that when FiFo is empty, it still receive any coming data.

Comment: Empty flag informs that FIFO contains no new data to be read.

Comment: I know that but are there any bad effects to design ?

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow and nor is it about programming. However... iIf something needs to read data from the FIFO and there is none to be read, then that could be a problem - it depends entirely on the application (what you're using your FIFO for). Even if it's not a problem per se, whatever is reading the FIFO still needs to be aware if there is nothing to read so that it doesn't try to read nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In certain cases EMPTY can be just as detrimental as the FIFO being full. Say you have a constant data rate to maintain and you need to be aware and send an error if you have ran out of data. The empty flag would be a way to indicate this. PCIe/USB and various other protocols use an Elastic Buffer which is essentially a FIFO with some additional logic. In this case, empty or full is *basically* the same error (data is invalid this cycle).

Whether or not EMPTY (or full even) is a good or bad condition is dependent on your application.